# Deserialize JSON different structure, but the same name in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am working, in C#, with some API and it returns "Errors" in JSON with 404 and 200(!) status code, but with different structures.

1) HTTP Status 200:

```
{ "Errors": "Duplicated" }
```

2) HTTP Status 200:

```
{ "Errors": {"some_key":"Invalid"} }
```

3) HTTP Status 404:

```
{ "Errors": "some_key1":["Invalid"], "some_key2":["Invalid"] }
```

1 - Maps to String - OK, but not to `Dictionary<string,string>`
2 - Maps to `Dictionary<string,string>`, but not to string
3 - Maps it to ModelState `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` OK, as the StatusCode is diff (I rename "Errors" in Json string and map it to diff property name.

The only issue is with case 1 and 2 as both are returned with the same HTTP Status code and the same node name "Errors".

Have anybody worked with these cases? How do you handle them? Is there any Netwon Json deserialzier setting to flatten Case 2 to just string or Case 1 into dictionary with 1,2,3.. autgenerated keys?

Any other idea?

Cheers

Comment: That technique to parse to JToken first and then checking if there is the "Error" node helped me. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm But this tight me with NewtonJson.

Answer (score 0):

Make your property a dynamic object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx. Then based on what properties are available you can convert it or can read the properties directly off the dynamic.